# API for paper check cutting

Tags: api, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I know this not actually a developer question, but I am hoping that I might draw on your collective experience in the industry.

I am looking for an company with an API which will allow me to issue printed checks. The only company I have found offering this so far is [WebmasterChecks](https://webmasterchecks.com/). However, I have not been able to find much information about this company, so I am not very reassured.

Do you know any company with an API which will allow me to issue printed checks?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: "I know this not actually a developer question." , didn't really have to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have been using them for about 2 years for our affiliate payments and they have been great, you can do everything you need to directly through the admin